# Working with files and folders using ZIP

Tags: php, html, zip

We have some html code like:

```
<body>Some text</body>
```

And a variable `$contents`.

Its first time I work with zip in php, have a couple of questions.

How do I:

1. create a folder named `HTML` and place it inside `$contents` (**no real creation on ftp**, just in variable)
2. create an `index.html` and place it inside `HTML` folder, which is inside `$contents`

   So the `$contents` before zip should contain:

   ```
    /HTML/index.html (with <body>Some text</body> code inside)
   ```
3. create a zip archive with all the content inside `$contents` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

```
$contents = '/tmp/HTML';
// Make the directory
mkdir($contents);
// Write the html
file_put_contents("$contents/index.html", $html);
// Zip it up
$return_value = -1;
$output = array();
exec("zip -r contents.zip $contents 2>&1", $output, $return_value);
if ($return_value === 0){
    // No errors
    // You now have contents.zip to play with
} else {
   echo "Errors!";
   print_r($output);
}
```

I'm not using a library to zip it, just the command line, but you could use a library if you  wished (but I am checking to see if `zip` executed correctly).

---

If you really want to do everything truly in memory, you can do this:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('contents.zip') === TRUE) {
    $zip->addFromString('contents/index.html', $html);
    $zip->close();
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfromstring.php

Comment: mkdir creates folder and file_put_contents creates file on ftp, what I don't want to do. The idea is to create folders and files inside variable and zip them as a result. No real creation, all the actions should be in memory. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: If you do everything in `/tmp`, that would technically satisfy your requirement because `/tmp` is a filesystem that is mounted in RAM (i.e. memory). However, please see my edit, for a way to do it entire in PHP's memory.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the [`ZipArchive`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) class. So you could have something like this

```
$html = '<body>some HTML</body>';
$contents = new ZipArchive();
if($contents->open('html.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE)){
    $contents->addEmptyDir('HTML');
    $contents->addFromString('index.html', $html);
    $contents->close()
}
```